# Unable to infer complex closure return type in capture list with multiple arguments

Tags: swift, closures

I've tried everything I can think of to fix this error. I hope the code is self-explanatory.

```
class Food {
    var foodWasEaten: ((Food) -> ())?
}

class Restaurant {
    
    var food: [Food] = []
    
    init() {
        let food = Food()
        let index = 0
        food.foodWasEaten = { [weak self, weak food, index] in
             // Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
            if let self = self,
                let food = food {
                self.foodWasEaten(food: food, index: index)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func foodWasEaten(food: Food, index: Int) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `foodWasEaten` is expected to have type `((Food) -> ())?`. The closure you provided takes no arguments, so the compiler is confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an argument to the closure. It can just be `_ in`:

```
init() {
    let food = Food()
    let index = 0
    food.foodWasEaten = { [weak self, weak food, index] _ in
        if let self = self,
            let food = food {
            self.foodWasEaten(food: food, index: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need a parameter in your closure, you can change the type of your closure:

```
class Food {
    var foodWasEaten: (() -> ())?
}
```

Then you can use your original approach:

```
food.foodWasEaten = { [weak self, weak food, index] in ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the completion parameter of type `Food`. Try this:

```
init() {
    let food = Food()
    let index = 0
    food.foodWasEaten = { [weak self, index] eatenFood in
        if let self = self {
            self.foodWasEaten(food: eatenFood, index: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This indeed work! But isn't eatenFood captured strongly?

Comment: eatenFood is the parameter returned from the completion block. It doesn't have a reference in this case. Your code uses the food from `Restaurant` and you're not using the food returned in the completion block.